# Is it possible to implement an auto scaling RDS enviroment with MariaDB in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, autoscaling

I'm googling about having a cluster of mariadb at AWS and make it work with auto scaling feature, but I didn't find the option "Add autoscaling replica" that appears in some tutorials. Since all tutorial samples that I have seen are using Aurora with MySql, I'm wondering if it's possible do this with mariadb. I would like to simply migrate to mysql but I need the RETURNING clause and some Uuid functions of mariadb-10.5, so I'm stucked to mariadb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS RDS Autoscaling is only available for Aurora. Aurora currently has PostgreSQL and MySQL compatibility.